# Subquery with Inner Join in HQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I want to print title from Movies table which has Foreign key Movie_id in Rating table.In rating table we have to get top 10 results based on movie_id occurrence .Since Limit is not allowed in HQL so **setMaxResults** is used

```
Query q=session.createQuery("select Title from Movies  as M Inner Join ( SELECT Movie_id, COUNT(*)  FROM Rating  GROUP BY Movie_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 10 ) as R ON M.Movie_id=R.Movie_id").setMaxResults(10);
```

**Exception is:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 59 [select Title from com.rahul.model.Movies  as M Inner Join ( SELECT Movie_id, COUNT(*)  FROM com.rahul.model.Rating  GROUP BY Movie_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 10 ) as R ON M.Movie_id=R.Movie_id]
```

Since HQL doesn't support subquery how to achieve it ?

Comment: Hql support subquery see link https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries

Answer (score 2):

You can write this query as a `JOIN`/`GROUP BY`:

```
select m.Title
from Movies m Inner Join
     Rating r
     on m.Movie_id = r.Movie_id
group by m.Movie_Id, m.Title
order by count(*) desc
limit 10;
```

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff Query    :                                                                                                     ' Query q=session.createQuery("select m.title from Movies m Inner Join Rating r on m.movie_id = r.movie_id group by m.movie_Id, m.title order by count(*) desc limit 10"); '                                                                                     Limit is not supported in HQL

Comment: **Exception** : org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: limit near line 1, column 161 [select m.title from com.rahul.model.Movies m Inner Join com.rahul.model.Rating r on m.movie_id = r.movie_id group by m.movie_Id, m.title order by count(*) desc limit 10]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved

> `Query q=session.createQuery("select m.title from Movies m Inner Join Rating r on m.movie_id = r.movie_id group by m.movie_id, m.title order by count(*) desc").setMaxResults(10);`